# Input validation for certain test not working as expected

Tags: c++, double, cin, validation

```
double checkInput() {
    double add;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cin >> add;
    if (cin.fail()==true)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Incorrect input"<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        return add;
    }
}
```

I use this bit of code to filter out character inputs eg "Blarg","bat12cat" and similar inputs where the character/letter come first but when i test with "1gold" ,"0.05cake" etc where number comes first then letters,the program accepts the all numbers up to the first instance of a letter.

My understanding is that it is the cin.ignore() that is causing the issue and is allowing the numbers through.

What would let inputs like"0.05Cats" be ignored/skipped altogether?.
Searching online,people suggest using getline() and stringstream.

Thank you.

Comment: No, `ignore()` isn't the problem, but the way `operator>>` works. When reading a `double` it collects characters that could be part of a `double` and then stops when finding something that cannot be. If it then holds a valid value, like `0.05`, it is satisfied with that and leaves the rest of the line for some other input. It cannot know if your code is `cin >>add>>animal`, for which `0.05Cats` would be perfect.

Comment: If you need some other parsing, you can use `getline` and then parse the string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you input something like `1.5dog` and then use `cin >> some_double;` `>>` is going to extract out a double until it can't read any more.  So `some_double` gets the 1.5 and `dog` is still in the stream.  This is not a failure and as such the failbit is not set.  Since it is not set you skip your if statement and return the double value while the rest of the input stays in the stream and will cause you issues the next time you try to read from the stream.  My suggestion is to change how you read your inputs.  You can take in the input via a `std::string` and then convert it to the desired type.  Then if the conversion fails you you can signal that you had a failure.  I would use something like:

```
bool read_double(std::istream & is, double & number)
{
    std::string line;
    getline(is, line);
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    double temp = stod(line, &pos);
    if (pos != line.size()) // there is extra content in the streams
        return false;
    number = temp;
    return true;
}
```

And you can see it working with this <kbd>[Live Example](https://ideone.com/VQ4rq7)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is more than one way to do the right thing. Using "c++(11) regex class object" would help you. You can edit regex for your needs (for example to include hex numbers by adding -a,b,c,d,e,f).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <regex>

void main()
{
    string input;
    std::regex reg("[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)");

    cout << "Please enter a double type\n";

    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if (std::regex_match(input, reg))
        {
            std::cout << "Valid input\n";
            break;          
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input\n";
            cout << "Please enter a double type\n";
        }

    }

    double do_with = std::stod(input,NULL);

    cout << "the double is : " << do_with << endl;

    cin >> input; // to hold the shell
}
```